# Using implicit intent to open activity

Tags: java, android

I'm getting the below error for `NumbersClickListener` class. I'm trying to use a intent to open `NumbersActivity`

All other activity can be opened using intents in the `MainActivity`. What is wrong with the code.

The implementation using `NumbersClickListener` class has some issue.

> ```
>  Error:(14, 20) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(NumbersClickListener,Class<NumbersActivity>)
> constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
> (argument mismatch; NumbersClickListener cannot be converted to String)
> constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
> (argument mismatch; NumbersClickListener cannot be converted to Context)
> ```

```
Error:(15, 9) error: cannot find symbol method startActivity(Intent)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

NumbersClickListener class :

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class NumbersClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onClick (View view)
    {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Opening Numbers Category",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, NumbersActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

The error is with these line of codes : Iv tried MainActivity.this also

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NumbersActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
```

Main Activity code

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import static android.R.id.message;
import static android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE;
import static com.example.android.miwok.R.id.phrases;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        NumbersClickListener clickListener = new NumbersClickListener();
        //Find views that shows number category
        TextView numbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbers);
        numbers.setOnClickListener(clickListener);



        TextView phrases = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phrases);
        phrases.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PhrasesActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        TextView family = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.family);
        family.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FamilyActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    public void openColorsList(View view) {
         // setContentView(R.layout.activity_colors);   //we can use this to colors xml in main actitvity
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ColorsActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is `Intent i = new Intent(this, NumbersActivity.class);` "this" is present of NumbersClickListener , to start activity you need context. So change it to :

```
Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), NumbersActivity.class);
```

or you need to pass context to NumbersClickListener to start an activity

Comment: Now startActivity(i) is red. Error:(15, 9) error: cannot find symbol method startActivity(Intent)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: view.getContext().startActivity(i)

Comment: your class NumbersClickListener dont have method startActivity but only on Context or Activity

Answer (score 0):

```
Error:(14, 20) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(NumbersClickListener,Class<NumbersActivity>)
```

**See**, your error says it all. You need first argument as `context` and second as the `class` (activity) name you want to open .

> All other activity can be opened using intents in the MainActivity

this is because your `MainActivity` is extended from `Activity` class and can refer to `context` using `this` but not all plain classes which are not having any reference to `Activity context`.

What you can do is

Create a reference to context ,something like

```
Context context = getContext();
```

and use this context instead of `this`

```
getContext()
```

can be a public method in your `MainActivity class` that returns `this`.

> Now startActivity(i) is red.

Do `context.startActivity(your_intent_here);`

*I Hope It helped :)*

Comment: So how come i can use startActivity(i) in MainActivity and not here. This is so confusing. How can i know all these ?

Comment: see my updated answer.. am still editing it to make it more clear. wait for my edits.

Comment: "This is so confusing. How can i know all these ? "

Yes , it would be if you are a beginner , keep learning :)

You can accept my answer and upvote it if you think it helped you , thanks!